# How to turn free space into unallocated on windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a windows 10 computer with two partitions: C:\ for programs and F:\ for documents. I would like to dual boot in Linux. I've shrinked the F:\ to create unallocated space, however it created free space instead. As I understand, I can't use this space to install linux afterwards. Can I change it to unallocated from Windows? Or may be join it back to F:\ and redo the process the right way to get unallocated space? Thank you in advance

**Edit:** here I did shrink the F:\ and got "Free space" instead of "Unallocated", like they show in most of the tutorials I've found. I think I'm missing something simple. It's mbr, not gpt (don't know if it is important). Sorry for the cyrillic.

[image: diskmgmt.msc]

Comment: The keywords you're looking for are "how to resize a partition"

Comment: @user253751 "how to resize a partition" did help to join free space back together, but I'm still confused how to create an unallocated space, as in most instructions I've read it's just "shrink volume > enjoy your unallocated space" and it didn't work out for me. May be it's because I have mbr\bios not gpt\uefi?

Comment: "unallocated space" isn't something you create -- it is the _absence_ of something, i.e. it's the space where no partitions are created yet. If you shrink a partition by 10 GB, this literally gives you 10 GB of "unallocated space".

Comment: @user1686 I used the shrink partition option on disk F:\, but I got "free space" (green) instead of "unallocated space" (black), may be I'm missing something sorry

Comment: Could you include a screenshot?

Comment: @user1686 yes, here it is

Comment: May be it's because F: is logic, not primary?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question right, your guess, that it is because you've got a logical partition, is correct. Space assigned to a logical partition can't be  (at least with windows tools) unassigend. You either have to do that with a live disc of GParted, or you could delete that partition alltogether, and recreate it. Backup your data, duh.